# Recommended mailing list manager for use with Postfix

Tags: software-rec, email

I have a small VPS (256MB RAM, 12% cap CPU) with Postfix installed that I use to host my mail domains. I want to run a mailing list manager, but would like to avoid Mailman because of its big fingerprint. Plus, I sysadmin a couple of them and would like to try new things :-)

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

The Postfix web site lists [several mailing list managers](http://www.postfix.org/addon.html#lists). Majordomo is listed there, and is pretty common, and I know it has run on systems with fewer resources than you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I used Mailman on Postfix with success. Its command-line administration is easily understandable. Caveat: they were all low-traffic lists.

Answer (score 0):

[Sympa](http://www.sympa.org/) works quite well with postfix. You have a [specific tutorial](http://www.sympa.org/faq/postfix_howto) for that. I have installed or used this combination several times for clients.

If you are concerned about footprint you might find Sympa disappointing as it is using a lot of different technology. But the functionality level is high, notably to integrate with databases and security options.

I prefer Mailman for my own small scale projects, I like the fact that it is written in Python and I am waiting for the new version 3 to be stable.